# How to add one column into existing SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table and it is located on a remote server. I can connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio but opening it takes time instead, I am doing my jobs with `SQL Query` window without reaching it.

Recently I've made a change on the local copy of this table and want to update the remote one as well. All I've done is adding one more column which is `Nullable` and I'd like to learn how to add this one more column to the remote SQL Server with `T-SQL` without ruining the remote one data.

**Here is the additional info:**

`Table Name: Products`

`Columns to be added: LastUpdate, Nullable and varchar(200)`

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `LastUpdate` a `varchar(200)`? Sounds like a date column.

Comment: Actually there is more than just a date.

Comment: Sounds like it should be more than one column then - generally good practice is one column per piece of data.

Comment: It is not something big that I need to think about better practices. It is just a temp projects and all it is needed to handle the current tasks.

Comment: if you do bad design often, when it doesn't matter, then you will end up doing bad design when it does matter. **NEVER put multiple pieces of data in a single column** you will forever be parsing out your values, just create multiple columns, it is really easy to do this the right way, so why not?

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I will keep stick to good practices.

Comment: why is this so highly viewed?

Comment: Sometimes putting multiple pieces of data in a single column can significantly speed up and simplify your schema. For example, suppose you want to store the last 5 selected numbers. You could create a table, a relation, and store 5 records in the database.  Or, you can store a string list 1,2,3,4,5. If you have no reason to do any special processing on 1,2,3,4,5 then store it as a list. To say NEVER put multiple pieces of data in a single column just isn't always the case. If needed you could always add the relational table at a future date.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The syntax you need is

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD LastUpdate  varchar(200) NULL
```

[This is a metadata only operation](http://sqlmag.com/blog/size-data-operations-when-adding-and-removing-columns)

Comment: @manosivam - I rejected [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3548507). The default nullability for new columns depends on [session and database options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx) and should not be assumed.

Comment: Link, you've given, points to a web page, that loads enormous amount of ads and external links to right sidebar, while leaving main page text completely empty. So I assume, that we may call that link "dead" or at least unusable.

Comment: @trejder - Thanks for the heads up. Looks like it is moved to http://sqlmag.com/blog/size-data-operations-when-adding-and-removing-columns

Answer (score 9):

What about something like:

```
Alter Table Products
Add LastUpdate varchar(200) null
```

Do you need something more complex than this?

Answer (score 1):

Its work perfectly

```
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD `LastUpdate` varchar(200) NULL;
```

But if you want more precise in table then you can try `AFTER`.

```
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD `LastUpdate` varchar(200) NULL AFTER `column_name`;
```

It will add `LastUpdate` column after specified column name (column_name).

Answer (score -1):

```
alter table table_name add field_name (size);

alter table arnicsc add place number(10);
```